# Spark ComboBox click issue

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I'm using a spark combobox in my AdvancedDataGrid, as an itemEditor. At some point I noticed that clicking on the scroll bar arrows would close the CB - very annoying. After much research I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506454/scrollbars-in-dropdownlist-inside-datagrid-itemeditor-not-working) on Stackoverflow which completely solved my problems - awesome!

One more and last lingering issue left though: when selecting an item from an open dropdownlist the mouse click seems to propagate to the cell below once the dropdown has closed. I assumed that the fix above would take care of this last issue, but it doesn't seem to. I tried to override the item_mouseDownHandler for the CB and stopImmediatePropagation() of the mouse event post its usual behavior, but that also seems to have no effect. I also tried setting the mouseChildren property for the skin['dropDown'] to false, but that impairs the whole functionality.

Would love any help / suggestions.

thank you all, as always

f

Answer (score 1):

Try `Event.StopPropagation();`

I think I had a similar issue where StopImmediatePropagation didnt work, but StopPropagation() did.